# xlwings unicode error when called from excel using Workbook.caller()

Tags: xlwings

I am trying to call python code from excel using xlwings. The name of the workbook is "wingsTest". If the first line in my called code is `wb = Workbook("wingsTest")` it runs fine but when `wb = Workbook.caller()` I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rbn\Documents\PythonScripts\apnlookupXL.py", line 74, in main
    wb = Workbook.caller()
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 182, in caller
    xl_workbook = xlplatform.get_xl_workbook_from_xl(fullname)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 429, in get_xl_workbook_from_xl
    if not is_file_open(unicode(fullname)):
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Thnks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been fixed with yesterday's 0.3.5 release, see [release notes](http://docs.xlwings.org/whatsnew.html#v0-3-5-april-26-2015).
Upgrade like so: `pip install --upgrade xlwings`